# Data Extract Requests via SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api

New to the Marketing Cloud and have a question regarding the ad-hoc data extract SOAP endpoint.  I wrote my own client and am able to auth however, I keep running into this fault:

```
    <ExtractResult>
      <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
      <StatusMessage>Unable to find a handler for extract ID: b13328a7-1ba7-42cc-8af1-89965a057504.</StatusMessage>
      <ErrorCode>31001</ErrorCode>
    </ExtractResult>
```

I'm providing a generated UUID for the ID node of the Requests.  Here's my request if that helps:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <oAuth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">
      <oAuthToken>***FILTERED***</oAuthToken>
    </oAuth>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
        <wsse:Username>*</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">***FILTERED***</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <tns:ExtractRequestMsg>
      <tns:Requests>
        <tns:ID>b13328a7-1ba7-42cc-8af1-89965a057504</tns:ID>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>StartDate</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>2016-09-12T11:55:55-04:00</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>EndDate</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>2016-09-12T13:55:55-04:00</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>ExtractSent</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>true</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>ExtractOpens</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>true</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>ExtractClicks</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>true</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>ExtractUnsubs</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>true</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>ExtractAttributes</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>true</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>Attributes</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>SendID,SubscriberKey,EventDate,EventType,BatchID,TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
        <tns:Parameters>
          <tns:Parameter>
            <tns:Name>OutputFileName</tns:Name>
            <tns:Value>b13328a7-1ba7-42cc-8af1-89965a057504.csv</tns:Value>
          </tns:Parameter>
        </tns:Parameters>
      </tns:Requests>
    </tns:ExtractRequestMsg>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Do I need to do anything special in order to run these extracts?  Maybe I'm going about this completely wrong but the issue seems to be related to my generated request ID.

Thanks in advance,
Sean

Comment: Well, answered my own question here.  The IDs can be fetched via a retrieve request on the extract description.